# putExtra em Spinner

Tags: android

Olá, no meu projeto tenho um `Spinner` de id `@+id/spnList`, que se encontra na minha atividade `Main`.
Esse `Spinner` é populado com tabelas criadas dinamicamente no banco de dados, até ai tudo funcionando perfeitamente.

O usuário clica em um botão onde leva ele a inserção de itens. Ao clicar no botão para ir até a atividade `InsertProduct`, dou um `putExtra` para pegar a tabela escolhida no `Spinner` da atividade `Main` para que o item seja adicionado a tabela escolhida pelo usuário. Apos ele adicionar o item, volta até a atividade `Main`, mas ao voltar a atividade `Main` a lista selecionada no `Spinner` é a primeira.
Vamos supor que eu tenha cinco listas e o usuário seleciona e adiciona um item a `Lista 5`, ao voltar para a atividade `Main` a lista selecionada no `Spinner` é a `Lista 1` e não a `Lista 5` como o usuário selecionou anteriormente.
Tentei dar um `putExtra` da atividade `InsertProduct` para `Main`, mas ele retorna como `null`
**Ex:**

```
-- Main --
// Função do botão de adicionar item
    Spinner spn = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnList);
    String strSpn = spn.getSelectedItem().toString(); // Vamos dizer que o valor sera "Lista 5"
    Intent i = new Intent(this, InsertProduct.class);
    i.putExtra("selectedItem", strSpn);
    startActivityForResult(i, 1);

// Função que exibi os itens na tela
    Controller controller = new Controller(getBaseContext());

    String[] list = controller.getData();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spnList.setAdapter(adapter);
    if (getIntent() != null && getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (!bundle.getString("setSelectedItem").equals(null)) {
            String setSpnSelected = bundle.getString("setSelectedItem");
            int spinnerPosition = adapter.getPosition(setSelectedItem);
            spnList.setSelection(spinnerPosition);
        }
    }

-- InsertProduct --
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String strSpn = extras.getString("selectedItem");

    String result = ... // Adiciona item a tabela "Lista"

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    returnIntent.putExtra("result", result);
    returnIntent.putExtra("setSelectedItem", strSpn);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
    finish();
```

Alguém sabe como posso manter a tabela selecionada pelo usuário mesmo após eu ir para outra atividade?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode salvar o estado da Activit sobrescrevendo o método  onSaveInstanceState() e restaurando com o método onRestoreInstanceState().

Seria mais ou menos assim.

```
void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState){
    outState.putCharSequence("selectedItem", spn.getSelectedItem());
}

void onRestoreInstanceState (Bundle savedInstanceState){
    spn.setSelectedItem(outState.getCharSequence("selectedItem"));
}
```

Comment: Como exatamente utilizo esses métodos? Sou iniciante em java e preciso de algo mais "mastigado" vamos dizer assim.

Comment: Seria Basicamente o código da minha resposta.

Comment: Ficaria `protected void onSaveInstanceState` e `protected void onRestoreInstanceState`? `onSave` na atividade `Main` e `onRestore` na atividade `InsertProduct`?

Comment: segue as referencias https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html?hl=pt-br     https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nu5mTPRTFqg